# c# app.config nested section

Tags: c#, app-config, custom-sections

I would like to have a nested custom section in the app.config as below, but struggling with the creating class objects in C#.

```
<customSettings>
    <brands>
       <brand name="abc">
          <mailbox server="" port="" />
          <mailbox server="" port="" />
       </brand>
       <brand name="xyz">
          <mailbox server="" port="" />
          <mailbox server="" port="" />
       </brand>
    </brands>
</customSettings>
```

Please help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are plenty of examples to achieve this out there. Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack has the best step by step instructions for doing custom configuration. It eeally helped me versus the MSDN documentation. http://particular.net/articles/generic-host-sample